# Adding style to RN element passed in props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am passing  element to a function as a prop (named image below), e.g.

```
const prettyImage = (props) => {
return (
   {props.image}
)}
```

Is there a way I can apply some styling (or generally pass some props) to `props.image` inside this function?

Comment: What about passing the props to directly to ```image``` while passing it as props to ```prettyImage```?

<PrettyImage image={<Image style={}/>} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `props.image` already is a JSX component, then this is not possible, since you want to pass a (styling) prop to a component that has already been created.

In other words: once the JSX component is created, there is no way to set its props afterwards.

I would restructure your component to achieve what you want. We have multiple choices here. Here are two of them.

**Option 1: props.image is the same component but with different props**

If the usage of `PrettyImage` only differs from the `props` passed to `props.image`, then we could create the JSX component currently stored inside `props.image` directly in `PrettyImage` and pass the necessary props to `PrettyImage` instead.

```js
const PrettyImage = (props) => {
   return (
       <Image uri={props.uri} size={props.size} style={props.style} />
   )
}
```

Making things explicit using Typescript.

```js
type PrettyImageProps = {
   uri: string,
   size: number,
   style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}

const PrettyImage = (props: PrettyImageProps) => {
   return (
       <Image uri={props.uri} size={props.size} style={props.style} />
   )
}
```

I am using `Image` here just as an example. The general pattern is the same for all components. In general I would call `PrettyImage` a wrapper component for `Image`.

**Option 2: Let props.image be the function name and use React.ceateElement**

We could also use the react high level API and use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to create any JSX component on the fly in our component `PrettyImage`. It is possible to pass any prop to this component.

Consider the following example.

```js
import React from "react"
import { Text } from "react-native"

function SomeImageComponent(props) {
  // or whatever. This is just a dummy
  return <Text style={props.style}>Hello</Text>
}

export default function App() {
  return <PrettyImage image={SomeImageComponent} />
}

export function PrettyImage(props) {
  // pass some styles
  return React.createElement(props.image, { style: { color: "red" } })
}
```

In the above code snippet it is indeed possible to pass a style object to any component since we create it at the same time.